# "Unrelentless" to mean "relentless"?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, non-standard

A native speaker commended someone for investigating something thoroughly, so they said "for your relentless investigating efforts", then they corrected themselves and said "unrelentless", then finally they thought maybe "relentless" was right after all. I suggested "unrelenting".

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unrelentless) states this use of "unrelentless" might be a malapropism. The non-standard variant appears in [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unrelentless&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), there has been continued interest for the word ([trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=unrelentless&hl=en)), the possible solecism is [discussed](https://www.oklahoman.com/story/lifestyle/2007/12/22/bucks-relentless-in-grammar-quest/61657259007/) in the context of other words beyond just discarding it, some opinions from other forums date to almost 20 years back so there is value in seeing if these have changed, and it also appears in some song lyrics (like Alanis Morissette's *Big Bad Love* (1992) "I wonder why I am so *unrelentless* / There's nothing that I can do to prevent this...") which seemingly haven't been corrected in the last 30 years.

Do you accept, or is "unrelentless" generally accepted to mean, "relentless" in this context; is it a malapropism or not, a solecism or a non-standard variant, and does that vary with regions? Which of the three adjectives do you find better suited in this context, and why?

Comment: it's **relentless** and **unrelenting**   There is no word *unrelentless. It would be like saying "unmercyless".

Comment: A little work with a dictionary and the simple logic of two negatives  cancelling would make it unnecessary to ask such a question about a non-existent word. Close?

Comment: @Anton How indefatigable, almost indisputable is this logic?

Comment: @livresque indubitably?

Comment: [unrelenting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unrelenting) is fine: it's in dictionaries. This definitely seems a question where a little thought and consulting dictionaries could have produced an answer with far less effort than posting here.

Comment: It is most certainly not a malapropism. A malapropism is the mistaken use of a word in place of a similar-sounding one, often with an amusing effect (e.g. ‘dance a flamingo ’ instead of flamenco ).

Comment: @MichaelHardy unbad?

Comment: @StuartF, the question is not about *unrelenting*.

Comment: @Greybeard it sound very much like the speaker used a mistaken word ("unrelentless") in place of a similar sounding one (either "relentless" or "unrelenting"), and thereby committed a malapropism.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner - which is why it isn't a malapropism. Malapropisms are quite distinctive - both words must be words that (i) have some similarities in their written appearance, and (ii) are both readily understood and (iii) currently part of general vocabulary of both speaker and audience: "unrelentless" is not such a word. (See Mrs Malaprop in Sheridan's "The Rivals".) https://www.thoughtco.com/mrs-malaprop-and-origin-of-malapropisms-3973512

Comment: There is no such thing as words that don't exist. Just words that are hard to find examples of use.

Comment: This is a bit tangential, but I suspect `relentless` is an example of an [orphaned negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unpaired_word), and while technically the opposite of `relentless` should be `relentful`, that word has dropped out of common usage.

Comment: @MatthewDaly I can't find any information to corroborate the idea that relentful is a form that has fallen out of usage. Rather I don't believe such a form was ever commonly used. Indeed it seems to me there is little need for one, since rarely is a thing consistently characterized by relent.

Comment: for the relentless*ness* of your investigating efforts - which is a noun? Wack.

Comment: @RMac It's pure speculation at this point. However, similar orphaned negatives are well-documented - phrases like "ruthful" and "gormful" are well-known to have fallen out of favour, while their negative counterparts remain in common use. Sorry, I didn't phrase it well - it meant to say that I *suspect* that "relentful" could be a similar phrase that has disappeared.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Do you accept, or is "unrelentless" generally accepted to mean, "relentless" in this context?

I very much doubt it. As the comments sum up, it's basically confusing *unrelenting* with *relentless*, formed on the same parallel as *irregardless*. (*irrespective* + *regardless*)

The same connection was brought up [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/unrelentless-irregardless.982822/) on Word Reference. But it is *not* standard English.

I've never heard this mistake before, and I'm pretty sure your friend was just overthinking it in the moment.

Sadly, it's been used in published, academic content:

> The decision to pursue MAID could provide considerable relief from the otherwise **unrelentless** work of illness and dying. [[link]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8582137/)

> Perfectionism is the **unrelentless** striving to avoid the guilt or shame of not working towards the inevitable and infinite next step of a rigid policy designed to avoid error. [[link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4461211/)]

I'd call it a non-standard variant, one that's been examined as far back as [1925](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Word_Study/0o0cAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0&bsq=unrelentless%20irregardless). Garner, in his (well, obviously 'Garner's') *Garner's Modern American Usage*, has an entry for *unrelentlessly*, which he describes as a 'nonword':

> **unrelentlessly* is a solecism for either *unrelentingly* or *relentlessly*. Ironically, this NONWORD literally suggests just the opposite of the intended meaning- e.g.:
>
> > "He has **unrelentlessly** [read *relentlessly* or, better, *faithfully*] served as a committee person involved in parks and recreation, fire prevention, police and emergency services, highway management, budget control and youth and school advisory committees." Letter of Larry E. Rice, "Change Dewitt Leader,"
> > [Post-Standard (Syracuse), 19 Oct. 1995, at 15.]
>
> > "This prime minister [Benjamin Netanyahu] is still under the shadow of public opinion, and the opposition will **unrelentlessly** [read *unrelentingly* or *relentlessly*] continue to fight against him through legal, moral and political means."
> > [Amos Perlmutter, "Dodging a Misguided Political Fusillade," Wash. Times, 22 Apr. 1997, at A14.]

Comment: This is all true, but it may be only a matter of time before some hardcore descriptivists start accusing those of us who object to *unrelentless* of being stuffy, narrow-minded prescriptivists.

Comment: I'm nonplussed.

Comment: @TinfoilHat minussed, so to say?

Comment: "As the comments sum up" You should include this information in the answer and the comments that are trying to answer the question should really be deleted.

Comment: @Laurel - Looks like some of them have already been deleted; my summary of the commented-information was _"basically confusing unrelenting with relentless, formed on the same parallel as irregardless. (irrespective + regardless)"_

Answer (score 2):

"Unrelent*ing*" would definitely have been better.

> extremely determined; never becoming weaker or admitting defeat:
> She
> will be remembered as an unrelenting opponent of racial
> discrimination.
>
> If you describe someone's behaviour as unrelenting, you mean that they
> are continuing to do something in a very determined way, often without
> caring whether they hurt or embarrass other people.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/unrelenting)

Comment: That *unrelenting* 'would definitely have been better' does not aswer the question, which is about the precise status of *unrelentless*.

Answer (score 1):

Un- means not. -less also means not. So unrelenting and relentless mean the same thing, not relenting.

Unrelentless is not a word, at least not according to my spelling checker :-) If it was a word, it would mean “not not relenting” which seems to be the opposite of what you wanted.

Comment: Agreed, and if someone raises the fact that it has been used, that is really no different from my habitual spelling of “the” as “teh”, except to note unrelentless has probably been used less often.